# Проблемы с кодировкой при шифровании

Tags: php, mysql, openssl

Использую данный класс для шифрования

```
     <?
namespace app\components;

class UnsafeCrypto
{
const METHOD = 'aes-256-ctr';

/**
* Encrypts (but does not authenticate) a message
*
* @param string $message - plaintext message
* @param string $key - encryption key (raw binary expected)
* @param boolean $encode - set to TRUE to return a base64-encoded
* @return string (raw binary)
*/
public static function encrypt($message, $key, $encode = false)
{
$nonceSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::METHOD);
$nonce = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($nonceSize);

$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
$message,
self::METHOD,
$key,
OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
$nonce
);

// Now let pack the IV and the ciphertext together
// Naively, we can just concatenate
if ($encode) {
return base64_encode($nonce.$ciphertext);
}
return $nonce.$ciphertext;
}

/**
* Decrypts (but does not verify) a message
*
* @param string $message - ciphertext message
* @param string $key - encryption key (raw binary expected)
* @param boolean $encoded - are we expecting an encoded string?
* @return string
*/
public static function decrypt($message, $key, $encoded = false)
{
if ($encoded) {
$message = base64_decode($message, true);
if ($message === false) {
throw new Exception('Encryption failure');
}
}

$nonceSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::METHOD);
$nonce = mb_substr($message, 0, $nonceSize, '8bit');
$ciphertext = mb_substr($message, $nonceSize, null, '8bit');

$plaintext = openssl_decrypt(
$ciphertext,
self::METHOD,
$key,
OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
$nonce
);

return $plaintext;
}
}
```

Если не загружать данные в БД, то всё ОК кодирует и декодирует нормально. После загрузки в бд (у неё кодировка utf8_general_ci) а затем при получении закодированных данных из бд и при попытке их расшифровать ничего не выходит. В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Поле БД блобовское? При чем тут кодировка? Двоичные данные не должны иметь кодировку.

Comment: Кодировка при том, что в БД записывались ведь не двоичные данные. Решение все таки нашел.

Comment: blob- поля для двоичных данных.